# Using the Kinect from Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt-creator, kinect

I have a machine running with windows 8.1, the kinect 2.0 for windows (and its SDK), visual studio community, and Qt Creator installed.  Right now I am trying to create a small app that pulls the joint data from the kinect and then outputs it in a text form on a GUI created in Qt Creator.

I have the microsoft examples for using the kinect in visual studio, but for creating and using GUI's I would prefer to use Qt Creator as it is what I use for all of my other projects.

My .pro file has the lines:

```
HEADERS += \
    ../../../../Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Kinect/v2.0_1409/inc/Kinect.h \
```

and

```
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Kinect/v2.0_1409/Lib/x64 -lKinect20
INCLUDEPATH += -L$$PWD/../../../../Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Kinect/v2.0_1409/Lib/x64
DEPENDPATH += -L$$PWD/../../../../Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Kinect/v2.0_1409/Lib/x64
```

This gives me the error:

```
LNK1104: cannot open file 'Files/Microsoft.obj'
```

what else do I need to be including to get this to work?

Comment: Did you mange to configurate it? We are trying same thing.

Comment: No, I was never able to configure it in QtCreator.  Instead I switched over to visual studio and just output command line info for what I was working with.  It wasn't as nice as I was wanting, but it was better than fiddling for days for getting some simple data from the kinect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to make some changes in the .pro file.

As the include path and the library files path contains spaces in it, Please use " " (double quotes) to skip/escape the spaces. The error you are getting would go with this.

Also remove -L$$PWD/../../../../ from the path and remove -l from -lkinect20 and add kinect20.lib instead.

Just look at my .pro file and make changes accordingly

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += "C:/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Kinect/v2.0_1409/Lib/x86/Kinect20.lib"

else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += "C:/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Kinect/v2.0_1409/Lib/x86/Kinect20d.lib"

else:unix: LIBS += "C:/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Kinect/v2.0_1409/Lib/x86/lKinect20.lib"

INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Kinect/v2.0_1409/inc"

DEPENDPATH += "C:/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Kinect/v2.0_1409/inc"

And i'm running my code in the release mode. Good to go.